# Is this a suggestion or an opinion?

Tags: idioms

I was speaking to my boss and he uttered a statement about "There is a meeting which I think you should join. Would you attend or go home straight".

I am confused. Is this a meeting I need to attend or is it optional? How do you interpret this?

Comment: He thinks you *should* attend the meeting, but he is *not* ordering you to do so. It is optional, but his language suggests that he would like it more if you go.

Comment: IMO, the second sentence that you quoted (“Would you attend or go home straight”) doesn’t make any sense.  Are you sure that that’s what he uttered?  If so, can you provide some context to clarify it?  For example, was the meeting in the building where you were (or nearby), or was it an hour’s drive away? near your home?  What was the timing?  Did he talk to you in late morning about a meeting in the early afternoon? at dinner time? the next day?  Or was the meeting about to start in a few minutes (or already started)? Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer.

Comment: @Scott It's reasonable to assume they meant "straight home".

Comment: My point is that we need to understand what the boss said, both in denotation and tone.  Did he say “I think you should attend this meeting. What do you think — does it look useful?” or did he say “I think you should attend this meeting. Do you want to defy me, or do you want to keep your job?” Given that we have an apparently mangled quote with no metadata, we can’t be sure.

Comment: Your boss didn't  say  "which I think might interest you" or "which I think you may want to join".  He said "which I think you should join".  Even if it is optional, anyone who wants climb up the ladder of success wouldn't hesitate to join.